# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb0

Tags: python, installation, setup.py

bei der Installation eines python Projekts tritt dieser fehler auf:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb0 in position 24: invalid start byte in scripts/ruff file at path: /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ruff-0.0.264-py3.11-linux-x86_64.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/ruff